# Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с такой задачей: есть строка

```
data = "sadsadsadsfffffffddd dddsfd dsd"
```

Как её разбить на отдельные символы? Понимаю, что `data.split()`, но только не понятно, что в `split()` писать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ну намудрили ...

```
result = list(data)
```

Comment: `list()` не нужно вызывать, [`data` *уже* последовательность в Питоне](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044). `str` это встроенное имя—лучше не использовать его как имя своей переменной.

Answer (score 14):

`data` уже является последовательностью (`data[i]` работает). Ничего вызывать не надо.

К примеру, чтобы напечатать каждый символ на отдельной строке:

```
for char in text:
    print(char)
```

Что можно кратко записать: `print('\n'.join(text))`. Если нужен именно Питон список, то просто `chars = list(text)`.

Если вы работаете с текстом, то используйте Unicode. Юникодные строки в Питоне являются неизменямыми последовательностями символов ([Unicode code points](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC,_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BE_Unicode_%D0%B8_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

Видимые пользователем буквы (grapheme clusters) могут состоять из нескольких символов, к примеру, `ё` буква может быть представлена как последовательность двух символов: U+435 U+308 в Unicode—`u'\u0435\u0308'` в Питоне:

```
>>> print(u'\u0435\u0308')
ё
```

Каждый символ может быть представлен в различных кодировках одним или несколькими байтами, к примеру, букву `я` (U+044F) можно закодировать в два байта: 11010001 10001111 в utf-8 кодировке:

```
>>> print(u'\u044f')
я
>>> u'\u044f'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xd1\x8f'  # два байта: 209, 143
```

Байты/байтовая строка (`bytes` тип) это неизменяемая последовательность байт в Питоне.

`str` тип является bytes в Питоне 2. `str` является Unicode в Питоне 3.

Кроме того существует понятие code unit (8 бит в utf-8, 16 бит в utf-16). Строки в Javascript можно часто рассматривать как последовательности utf-16 code unit ([может иметь значение при переносе функциональности в Питон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592971/23044)), к примеру, смайлик  (U+1F602) символ представлен как два code unit: D83D DE02 в utf-16(BE) кодировке:

```
>>> print(u'\U0001F602')

>>> u'\U0001F602'.encode('utf-16be')
b'\xd8=\xde\x02'  # четыре байта: 216, 61, 222, 2
```

То есть, если у вас текст, представленный как `str` в Питоне 3 (Юникод), то вы можете его рассматривать как различные последовательности в зависимости от задачи:

```
>>> import regex  # $ pip install regex
>>> text = 'я  ё'         # 6 code points
>>> print(ascii(text))
'\u044f \U0001f602 \u0435\u0308'
>>> regex.findall(r'\X', text) # 5 grapheme clusters
['я', ' ', '', ' ', 'ё']  # 5 user-perceived characters
>>> utf16codeunits(text)    # 7 utf-16 code units
(1103, 32, 55357, 56834, 32, 1077, 776)
>>> text.encode('utf-16be') # 14 bytes in utf-16
b'\x04O\x00 \xd8=\xde\x02\x00 \x045\x03\x08'
>>> text.encode('utf-8')    # 12 bytes in utf-8
b'\xd1\x8f \xf0\x9f\x98\x82 \xd0\xb5\xcc\x88'
```

где [`utf16codeunits()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592971/23044).

Answer (score 8):

Для начала вопрос - а для чего разбивать-то? Если нужно обращаться к каждому символу отдельно, то это можно делать так:

```
data[i]
```

а по теме: .split работает так:

```
arr = data.split('<символ(ы) для разделения>')
```

получается массив arr. Если вы поставите символ для разделения " " (пробел), то в массиве у вас будет три элемента.

Comment: Добавлю, что на 2.7 ( и скорее всего на любой версии ) при
 
    data.split('')

Даёт исключение 

    ValueError: empty separator

Comment: у меня 3.2, не помню таких проблем... может, я по пробелу и не сплитил никогда

Comment: Я написал без пробела

Comment: Я понимаю как работает split(). Я хочу считать файл    file_in = open('in.txt', 'r').read() - так он считается в одну строку, затем разбить её на отдельные символы, получится список из символов, затем сделать как-бы сделать частотный анализ, т.е. 


data = [[a,4], [s,6], [e, 9]]


Как-то так, если знаете, какой-либо другой подход или как-то по другому реализовать задачу, то напишите, пожалуйста, буду благодарен:)

Answer (score 2):

Вот ваш реальный вопрос: Как сделать частотный анализ встречаемости символов

На псевдо-коде ( он-же JS ) так:

```
str = "содержание_вашего_файла"
res = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ){
  var ch = str[ i ];
  if ( !res[ ch ] ) res[ ch ] = 1;
  else res[ ch ]++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Код анализа.

```
text = 'hello world'
unique_letters = set(text)
analize = {}
for letter in unique_letters:
    analize[letter] = text.count(letter)

print analize # => {' ': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'w': 1}
```

Comment: Представляете, как это будет работать со строкой, скажем, в пару сотен килобайт?

Comment: Представляю, попробовал на тексте в 50 мегабайт. Работает шустро, понимаю что будет жрать память, можно все это дело оформить в виде генератора.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections, io

stats = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

with open('some.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for char in line:
            stats[char] += 1
```

Или так, что бы не плодить вложенные циклы:

```
import collections, io
from itertools import chain

stats = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

with open('some.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for char in chain.from_iterable(fp):
        stats[char] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Будет прекрасно работать на массиве любого размера через выражение-генератор. Массив в память при этом не загружается:

```
text = 'hello world'
indecies = set(text)
values = (text.count(letter) for letter in indecies)
analize = dict(zip(indecies, values))
```

Comment: Только прочитал, всё что написали, большое спасибо за помощь!
А я некоторый свой варианет написал:



file_in = open('in.txt', 'r').read()
exampleData = ",".join("[%s,'%s']" % (file_in.count(i) , i) for i in sorted(set(file_in)))




получается конечно же строка, а в python-не  можно просто привести эту строку к типу list?
Если сделать так, то не совсем то получается: list(
exampleData).

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен список, то так:

```
data = "sadsadsadsfffffffddd dddsfd dsd"
l = list(data)
print(l)

['s', 'a', 'd', 's', 'a', 'd', 's', 'a', 'd', 's', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'd', 'd', 'd', ' ', 'd', 'd', 'd', 's', 'f', 'd', ' ', 'd', 's', 'd']
```

Comment: По смыслу то же самое что в принятом ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, лучший вариант

```
data = "sadsadsadsfffffffddd dddsfd dsd"
list(data)
```

Но еще хороший вариант:

```
[c for c in data]
```

Comment: это не генератор

Comment: Спасибо, исправила

Answer (score 0):

В кавычках знак который разделяет символы:

```
s=input()
l=list(''.join(s))
print(l)
```

---

```
rgbycm

['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'm']
```

---

Чтобы просто вывести символы через пробел без квадратных скобок и кавычек:

```
s=input()
l=' '.join(s)
print(l)
```

---

```
rgbycm

r g b y c m
```

Comment: Если что, `''.join(s)` равно исходной строке (`s`). Зачем такие извращения?

Comment: `В кавычках знак который разделяет символы` - не верно. `join` предназначен для объединения последовательности (например, списка или любой другой итерируемой последовательности) строк, собирая их в одну строку с указанным разделителем. Таким образом, вы сначала разделяете строку на отдельные символы, а потом собираете обратно в целую строку (то что было, то и получили: `s == ''.join(s)`), а потом снова разбиваете на список из отдельных символов. В первом куске кода второй строкой можно просто записать `l=list(s)`.