# Как перевести из Javascript в Питон функцию хэширования строки

Tags: javascript, python, хеширование, hashcode

Необходимо переделать фун-цю хеширования с JS на Python для протокола между ними.И вот тут возник затык.Если проверяю на короткой строке результат одинаковый ,а если строку увеличить то выходят расхождения.Уже запутался и не знаю куда смотреть.

Код JS:

```
function hashCode(str) {
  var hash = 0, i, chr, len;
  if (str.length == 0) return hash;

  for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    chr   = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0;
  }
  return hash;
};
```

И мой код в Python :

```
def hashCode(indx):
    indx = str(indx)
    hval = 0
    if not len(indx):
        return hval

    for i in indx:
        hval = ((hval << 5) - hval) + ord(i)
        hval = ctypes.c_int32(hval).value
    return ctypes.c_uint32(hval).value
```

Если проверить на равенство обе фун-и на примере строки "uyfwqewww" то получим 1041672786.А если строку увеличить то получаю расхождение.В побитовых операциях не силен,поэтому прошу сильно не бить)

Comment: На каких данных какие результаты получаете?

Answer (score 2):

[`str.charCodeAt(i)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.charcodeat) возвращает 16-битное целое число без знака. Обычно это utf-16 code unit. Поэтому обход строки в JavaScript из кода в вопросе:

```javascript
var i, chr, len;
for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  chr = str.charCodeAt(i);
  console.log(chr);
}
```

Можно реализовать в Питоне как:

```py
import struct

def utf16codeunits(text):
    bytestring = text.encode('utf-16be')
    return struct.unpack('>{}H'.format(len(bytestring)//2), bytestring) 

for u16 in utf16codeunits(text):
    print(u16)
```

[Числа в JavaScript представлены интересным способом](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type). К примеру, максимальное число ([`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-number.max_safe_integer)) равно 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. Но результаты побитовых операций ограничены [32-битными числами со знаком](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-left-shift-operator). Сложение/вычитание работает как для [IEEE 754-2008 `double`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from functools import reduce

def ToInt32(n):
    n &= 0xffffffff # 32-bit 
    return n - 2**32 if n >= 2**31 else n

def hash_code_javascript(text):
    return reduce(lambda h, u16: ToInt32(ToInt32(h << 5) - h + u16),
                  utf16codeunits(text), 0)
```

Пример для `'a ☺ \n'` строки:

```javascript
> hashCode('a \u{263a} ' + String.fromCodePoint(0x1f602) + '\n') // JS
1608199136
```

```py
>>> hash_code_javascript('a \u263a \U0001f602\n')  # Python
1608199136
```

Более лёгким путём был бы выбор какой-либо стандартной хэш-функции, доступной как в JavaScript так и Питоне, не реализовывая подобные функции самостоятельно.