# is upper для русского языка

Tags: c++, строки, кириллица

Как проверить первый символ переменной типа std::string на принадлежность к верхнему регистру с учетом правил русского языка?
Есть что-то готовое или как это сделать ручками?

Comment: `isupper(s[0])`

Comment: @Harry для русского языка не работает.

Comment: Вопросы кодировки строк в C++ сброшены на программиста. Так что вопрос — в какой кодировке ваша строка?

Comment: Чисто формально - *"Какие символы являются буквами и какие буквы являются прописными, зависит от текущих установок локали для категории LC_CTYPE, которые вы можете получить или изменить с помощью функции setlocale()."*

Comment: @VladD utf-8 пологаю, т.к. линукс

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать ручками на основе кодов символов

[image: Таблица кодов букв русского языка в Unicode]

Для начала проверяем, лежит ли символ в диапазоне заглавных букв:

```
(letter >= 1040 && letter <= 1071) || letter == 1025
```

`letter == 1025` — отдельная проверка для буквы `Ё`.

Если да, то ничего не делаем, а если нет, то проверяем буква ли это вообще (вдруг там число в начале строки).

```
letter => 1072 && letter <= 1103   // (пока без учёта буквы ё)
```

Напомню, что, когда к типу `char` применяются операции сравнения или арифметические операции, то работа идёт именно с кодом символа, а не с самим символом.

Итак, мы выяснили, что наш символ — это буква в нижнем регистре. Чтобы перевести её в upper case достаточно уменьшить её код на 32, что прекрасно видно из таблицы выше( код `A` — 1040, код `a` — 1072; 1072-1040 = 32).

```
char letter = 'a';

letter -= 32;
```

Теперь `letter = 'A'`, что нам необходимо.

Осталось отдельно обработать случай с буквой `ё`, когда:

```
letter == 1105
```

Comment: Это unicode (т.е. имеет смысл для wchar_t), а у автора наверняка utf-8 (char[], для русских букв по 2 байта на символ) / (Ручками русские буковки в utf можно взять из https://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL и https://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW)

Comment: @avp `wchar_t` может быть недостаточно, чтобы произвольную Unicode code point хранить (на Windows  для UTF-16 code units этот тип используется). Unicode часто подводные камни имеет, лучше готовую библиотеку использовать (типа glib, ICU или другую в зависимости от требований проекта).

Comment: @jfs, справедливо, но неужели применение islower/isupper к суррогатным парам будет отличаться от их вызова  с любой из половинок? =)

Comment: @avp конечно могут отличаются. Свойства не BMP символа никак не связаны со свойствами отдельных половинок, когда он в виде суррогатной пары представлен. К тому же не стоит отождествлять utf-16 code units и Unicode code point (это нарушение абстракции, как к примеру можно было наблюдать на узких сборках Python 2 или в JavaScript. Посмотрите на [пример разницы между байтами, code unit для какой-либо кодировки, Unicode code point, grapheme clusters (символы воспринимаемые пользователем) для одного и того же текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044))

Comment: @jfs, откровенно говоря, не понял. Время позднее, подумаю еще завтра. Пока же остаюсь при своем мнении и вот почему. Любая "половинка" суррогатной пары сама по себе invalid (ей ни какой unicode не соответствует). Соответственно, вызов isupper/islower для нее даст false. С другой стороны, этими парами (они valid) кодируются разные древние иероглифы и т.п. изображения, и поверить, что к ним всерьез можно применить понятия upper/lower я не могу, т.е. результат вызова тоже будет false. Такая вот цепочка рассуждений в обоснование краткого комментария.

Comment: @avp: вы имеете право на своё мнение, но не на свои факты. Легко убедиться, что [существуют астральные символы, у которых islower() или isupper() возвращает true](http://ideone.com/LBjYGj)

Comment: @jfs, вот это другое дело, убедили. / (замечательная штука, этот питон, надо будет все же освоить...)

Comment: @avp: с Питоном можно за полдень ознакомиться: [пройдите в REPL официальное вводное руководство (есть на русском и как книжка)](https://goo.gl/tLXyCT), чтобы узнать основы языка и стандартной библиотеки. Прочтите [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](https://goo.gl/Au9u), чтобы духом проникнуться. Попробуйте знакомые задачки, но реализуйте их, используя Питон как исполняемый псевдо-код или как клей, который связывает компоненты с помощью [Awesome Python библиотек](https://awesome-python.com/), к примеру, [web crawler реализуйте](https://goo.gl/2t9NrV). Будут вопросы, спрашивайте.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо (уже открыл вкладки по ссылкам). Вообще-то, я читал и Гвидо и Бизли (и язык мне симпатичен (только скобочек не хватает =)). А вот пописать на нем (а значит как следует запомнить множество уже готовых полезных штучек, использование которых как раз позволяет делать компактный код) как-то руки не доходят...

Comment: @avp: если язык не экономит время в итоге (за счёт идей или непосредственного применения), то  и учить его не стоит. Только читая, не программируя, выучить язык очень тяжело. Можно хоть как калькулятор Python REPL использовать. Чтобы код и текст вперемежку шли, для заметок удобно jupyter notebook использовать ([пример воссоздания графика из знаменитого TED talk](https://goo.gl/Q7XwD7)), тесты писать (даже для С кода, браузера (selenium)), devops, от [микроконтроллеров](http://micropython.org) до [гигантских роботов](https://goo.gl/hhRojF), автоматизация https://automatetheboringstuff.com/ etc.

Comment: @jfs, ну, что без практики не выучить, это как говорится, и ежу понятно. А вот за наводку на  http://micropython.org/ с bare metal огромное спасибо (не поверите, может скоро на новой работе и пригодится (тьфу-тьфу, чтобы не сглазить))