# Программа подсчета символов

Tags: c

Вот пример из пособия от Брайана Кернигана.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
 double nc;
 for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc);
 printf ("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

А вот он же, но из cs50:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

int counter = 0;
while (true)
{
printf("%i\n",  counter); 

counter++;
}
```

И я уже вконец запутался, как все-таки он должен выглядеть. Ведь ни работает ни тот, ни другой.

Comment: Ну второй явно ничего не подсчитывает, потому что там просто бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Ответ зависит от того что символом в вашем случае вы хотите рассматривать. [Пример для Питона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044)

Comment: В идеале - хотелось бы узнать как считать все символы, включая пробелы до тех пор ,пока не будет осуществлен переход на новую строку нажатием enter

Comment: @PavelBobrov я не об этом. Вы по ссылке перейдите и посмотрите примеры разницы между байтами, code units, Unicode code points, graphemes clusters (символы, воспринимаемые пользователем). К примеру, буква `я` это два байта на этой странице (utf-8 кодировка используется). От задачи зависит: хотите вы 2 вернуть (закодировано используя два байта), если на входе `я` или 1 (как один символ считать).

Comment: Что делает 2 код?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так это должно было выглядеть.

```
int main(void)
{
  string s = GetString();
  int n = 0;
  while (s[n] != '\0')
    {
       n++;
    }
  printf("%i\n", n);
}
```

Comment: `GetString()` из `cs50.h` читает строку (заканчивающуюся на `'\n'` -- символ новой строки) из ввода (возвращает C строку, заканчивающуюся на `'\0'`, не включая `'\n'`). Это отличается от первого примера в вопросе, который всегда до конца (возможно многострочного) ввода  читает (до EOF). C тем же успехом (вместо вашего кода), вы можете просто `n = strlen(s)` использовать.

Comment: Или так. Разницы никакой, как мне кажется. Проще, или короче код все ровно не стал. Однако для `strlen` нужно подключать еще одну библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, что вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int nc;
    for(nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc);
    printf ("%d\n", nc);
}
```

Только не забудьте по окончанию ввода нажать Ctrl-Z (В Linux, насколько я помню, Ctrl-D, что ли...)

Второй код - просто бред какой-то...

Comment: Можно упомянуть что это считает байты в стандартном вводе (`wc -c`). Ещё можно `uintmax_t` и `PRIuMAX` использовать.

Comment: Не сочтете ли Вы за труд привести так же `while` цикл для завершения программы?
С синтаксисом этих циклов я уже знаком, а вот условие выхода никак сообразить не могу.

Comment: `while(getchar() != EOF) ++nc;` - вместо `for`, только `nc` обнулите предварительно. Вы это спрашивали?

Comment: не совсем. Этот тот же код, но записан с циклом `while`, вместо `for`.
Я же хотел просто придумать выход из программы без сочетания клавиш ctrl+d.

Comment: Что-то вроде       `do...` `...while (getchar() != 27)` 
Который значит: делай это пока не будет введен 27 символ, который соответствует клавише enter. 
Но все оказалось не так просто. После nfrb[ bpvtytybq  программа перестала реагировать даже на ctrl+d

Comment: Представленный вами цикл - выполняй, пока не введено нечто - т.е. как минимум подсчитает на 1 символ больше. Далее, `getchar()` не предусмотрен для отлова нажатий всяких клавиш типа Esc (с кодом 27) или Enter (с кодом 13). Для этого нужно использовать `getch()`... Но `getch()` не понимает признака конца файла, так как работает с клавиатурой, а не с потоком.

Comment: Послушайте, если вы хотите, чтоб вам помогли - сформулируйте ясно, что вы хотите. Я отвечал на вопрос, как должен выглядеть работающий код. Я ответил. Но, похоже, вас интересует вовсе не это. Так не заставляйте вытягивать из вас, что именно...

Comment: @Harry. Таки вот тот код, который я хотел получить.(см.выше). Подсчет символов завершается вводом нулевого символа , он же - конец строки, а значит = клавише enter