# Создание из списка словаря. Подсчет букв в списке

Tags: python

Передо мной стоит следующая задача, есть список букв:

```
list = "AaaBbBCcDdddGggPpjjJ"
```

Мне нужно посчитать количество букв в списке и вывести на экран ту букву, которая попадается в списке максимальное количество раз.

Я вижу следующее решение с подсчетом букв:

```
list = ( ", ".join("%s : %s" % (i, a.count(i)) for i in sorted(set(a.lower())))).split(',')
print(list)
```

Получается следующий список:

```
['a : 2', ' b : 1', ' c : 1', ' d : 3', ' g : 2', ' j : 2', ' p : 1']
```

Теперь стоит задача вытащить из этого списка ту самую наиболее часто используемую букву. Мне кажется, что если я преобразую данный список в словарь, то по максимальному значению смогу получить требуемый результат.

```
{a:2}, {b:1}, {c:1} и т.д.
```

Но вот незадача, - я не могу понять, как это сделать?

Comment: В питоне нет типа *символ*, поэтому строка не является *списком символов*. Во многом похоже, но строка и список - разные типы.

Comment: @andy.37 в программировании слово "символ" часто используется, чтобы обозначить элемент строки (элемент текста). Точнее нужно было бы сказать, что строка это *последовательность* символов (так как слово "список" со встроенным типом list может путаницу вызвать). Но неформально можно и слово список использовать (как синоним "последовательность"). В общем случае, символом может быть и байт, и code unit, и code point и grapheme cluster, и glyph, и что-нибудь ещё в зависимости от среды и задачи). Пример: [Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044)

Comment: @jfs Я это все понимаю. Просто именно в питоне (впрочем не только в нем) строка - довольно "специальная" последовательность. И даже итерируясь по строке (забавное слово) `for symbol in "abcd":` на каждом  шаге мы будем получать именно строку, просто состоящую из одного символа (в отличие от большинства других языков). И свойства строки `"abc"` довольно сильно отличаются от свойств списка (последовательности) "символов" `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В пакете `collections` есть все, что вам нужно для данной задачи =)

```
import collections
s = "AaaBbBCcDdddGggPpjjJ"
#если регистрозависимая разница, иначе к list применить метод lower()
print(collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0])
```

Comment: `Counter` хорошо использовать, когда у вас уже есть последовательность нормализованных букв. Подсчёт Unicode code points не всегда подходит. Иногда [по другим критериям следует строку разбить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044). Также `lower()` не всегда подходит для нормализации регистра букв. См. [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551443/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Как уже было сказано `Counter` отличный вариант, но можно сделать и простым генератором:

```
In [30]: _str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaavcdffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'

In [31]: result = {key : _str.count(key) for key in set(_str)}

In [32]: sorted(result.items(), key = lambda item: item[1])[-1]
Out[32]: ('f', 28)
```