# Перемешать буквы python

Tags: python

Помогите перемешать буквы в словах текст
в Этом коде ничего не происходит

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import random
a = "some text"
a1 = word_tokenize(a)
for i in a1:
    random.shuffle(i.split())

print(' '.join(a1))
```

Comment: Ну логично. Ты же перемешиваемый массив вообще не используешь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import random

text = "some text"
words = text.split()
for i, word in enumerate(map(list, words)):
    random.shuffle(word)
    words[i] = ''.join(word)

print(*words)  # -> eosm txet
```

Строки неизменяемы в Питоне, поэтому чтобы перемешать буквы в словах текста, каждое слово преобразуются в список символов, список перемешивается, затем объединённые символы назад в список слов присваиваются.

В общем случае, слова на буквы можно не только посимвольно (на отдельные Unicode code points) разбивать. См. [Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/52873/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вот такой вариант:

```py
import random

slovo = 'Привет'
slovo_list = list(slovo)
abrakadabra = random.sample(slovo_list,  len(slovo_list))

print(abrakadabra)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Более простой способ:

```
# Программа, которая меняет местами буквы в слове.
# Импортирую модуль random
import random

# Запрашиваю слово у пользователя.
слово = input("Введите слово, в котором вы хотите поменять буквы местами:\n")
# Преобразую введённое слово из неизменяемого строкового типа (str) 
# в изменяемый тип список (list) при помощи функции list()
слово = list(слово)
# Перемешиваю элементы списка при помощи метода.shuffle
random.shuffle(слово)
# Создаю переменную строкового типа, в которую будет записываться слово
# с перемешанными буквами.
перемешанное_слово = ""
# При помощи цикла for добавляю последовательно буквы
# в созданную пустую переменную (перемешанное_слово).
for буква in слово:
    перемешанное_слово += буква
# Вывожу результат на экран.
print(перемешанное_слово)
```