# Python3. Сортировка словаря по убыванию значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, словари

Необходимо отсортировать словарь по убыванию значений, составленный из количеств повторений в txt файле каждого символа, типа {символ:количество его повторений в файле}. Вот что у меня есть:

```
import re #библиотека для работы с регулярными выражениями
frequency = {} #пустой словарь
document_text = open('text.txt', 'r') #открываем файл на чтение
text_string = document_text.read().lower() #убираем капс
match_pattern = re.findall(r'.', text_string) #берем все символы из файла

for word in match_pattern: #обычный счетчик
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys() #keys для возврата ключей в словаре

for words in frequency_list:
    a = {words:frequency[words]}
    b = sorted(a.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0])) #Данная конструкция прекрасно работает, если мы создаем и наполняем словарь непосредственно в программном коде, но в данной ситуации, эта строчка просто никак не влияет на вывод результата.
    print(b)
```

**Я явно чего то не понимаю, будьте добры, подскажите**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть специальный класс счетчик - [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open(r'C:\download\Gogol_N._Revizor.txt', encoding='cp1251') as f:
    text = f.read().casefold()  # more aggressive "lower()"

c = Counter(list(text))
```

Результат:

```
In [201]: c.most_common(20)
Out[201]:
[(' ', 19825),
 ('о', 11764),
 ('е', 9251),
 ('а', 8853),
 ('т', 7564),
 ('и', 7178),
 ('н', 6749),
 ('с', 5348),
 ('в', 4950),
 ('р', 4569),
 ('к', 4108),
 ('л', 3796),
 ('д', 3605),
 ('у', 3247),
 ('м', 3161),
 ('п', 2995),
 (',', 2891),
 ('\n', 2844),
 ('.', 2497),
 ('ч', 2467)]
```

Если вызвать `.most_common()` без параметров, то получите все вхождения отсортированные в порядке убывания частоты.

Из `docstring`:

```
In [203]: c.most_common?
Signature: c.most_common(n=None)
Docstring:
List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.
```

Answer (score 3):

Словари не упорядочены в Питоне (до Питона 3.7). Поэтому их нельзя было отсортировать (так чтобы это работало на разных реализациях Питона).

На практике, "не упорядочен" значит, что любое изменение словаря может изменить порядок итерации. Если нужен определённый порядок, то необходимо было использовать упорядоченные структуры данных, к примеру, список (такой как возвращаемый `collections.Counter.most_common()`) или `collections.OrderedDict` (порядок вставки).

Чтобы отсортировать словарь, нужно создать упорядоченный словарь (добавить элементы в нужном порядке). Для частоты символов (Unicode codepoints — пренебрегая Unicode нормальными формами, Unicode grapheme clusters. См. [Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/52873/23044)) без учёта регистров на Питоне 3.7 можно получить отсортированный словарь (в порядке убывания частоты), используя `collections.Counter` (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter
from pathlib import Path

d = dict(Counter(Path('text.txt').read_text().casefold()).most_common())
```

До Питона 3.7:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict(Counter(Path('text.txt').read_text().casefold()).most_common())
```