# Как выводить из строки слова которые содержат только парное количество букв?

Tags: python

Дана строка символов, которая состоит из отдельных слов разделенных пробелом. Вывести через print все слова строки которые содержать парное количество букв.

Comment: в чём у вас сложности? Как разбить строку на слова? (по пробелам: `words = s.split()`) Как посчитать количество букв? [Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/52873/23044) «Парное» это чётное?

Comment: Проблема с выводом слов которые содержат только четное количество букв

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество букв в слове:

```
len(word)
```

Тест числа на четность:

```
if number % 2 == 0:
```

Вместе:

```
if len(word) % 2 == 0:
```

Целый код:

```
for word in text.split():
    if len(word) % 2 == 0: 
        print(word)
```

(Предпологается, что в переменной `text` уже есть нужный текст.)

Comment: Можно добавить и пример по вопросу: `for word text.split():if len(word) % 2 == 0: print(word)`

Comment: @gil9red - Спасибо, добавил.

Comment: Я опечатался, правильный for: `for word in text.split()`. Не забывайте проверять код, от ошибок никто не застрахован :)

Comment: @gil9red - Хороший собет. :-)

Comment: [одна буква может больше одного символа в строке занимать.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044)