# Как печатать длину строки для каждой вводимой строки Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

На вход копируются строки вместе столбиком:

```
abcd
----------
efg
----------
```

Не получается печатать длину каждой строки, печатается только длина первой.

```
for x in input().splitlines():
    print(len(x))
```

Comment: Не уверен, но кажется ваш пример совпал с форматирование markdown. Поместите пример в тег код или цитата. Кнопка `править`

Comment: Не понял, что вы имеете в виду, мне нужно, чтобы не запоминая программа выводила длинну каждой строки символов, копируемой в консоль. Каждая строка символов копируется на отдельной строчке.

Comment: У вас в вопросе данные такие: `abcd efg`, но в тексте вопроса `abcd----------efg----------` что из этого истинно? А по поводу вашей проблемы, скорее всего когда вы вставляете текст в input, то в него попадает первая строка `abcd\n`, потому что она первая заканчивается на `\n`. Почему бы вам данные для программы не брать из файлика?

Comment: Верный текст вопроса:), можно ли сделать, чтобы вычислялась и печаталась длинна каждой строки?(Я не знаю как это правильно написать, но все строки копируются за 1 раз в input столбиком)

Comment: Ок, я подправил форматирование вопроса. Мне кажется, для вашей задачи `Input` не очень подходит, предлагаю из файлика вытаскивать. Показать?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться сам как вытаскивать из файла:)

Comment: в сторону: в общем случае "длина строки" это не просто len(). К примеру, есть wcwidth модуль. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/52873/23044

Answer (score 2):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(len(line) - 1)             # Длина вез знака '\n'
```

Для ввода строк используется метод `input()` вставленного модуля [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html).

Строки читаются до тех пор, пока ввод не окончится признаком конца файла (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).
Когда вы хотите окончить ввод *простым нажатием на клавишу <kbd>Enter</kbd>*, прибавите код для теста ввода строки с длиной `1` (только знака конца строки: `\n`):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    if len(line) == 1:
        break
    print(len(line) - 1)
```

Comment: в конце может не быть символа новой строки. Можно `len(line) - line.endswith('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

`input` вызывается и читает один раз (до перевода строки). Если вызывать `input` в цикле, то получится что-то похожее. Но лучше используйте sys.stdin