# Как вырезать только строки, которые не имеют повторяющихся символов (cut/sed/awk) или Python?

Tags: python, linux, sed, awk

Как вырезать из массива текста только те строки, в которых любой символ в строке не повторяется, при этом не важно что это за символ и на каких он позициях в строке?

Если универсального алгоритма нет, то тогда как это сделать, зная набор всех символов (буквы, цифры) для всего массива (ряд строк могут не иметь общих символов между собой, но входят в набор символов для всего массива) и длину строк?

Как вариант, можно Python, если это проще.
Спасибо

Comment: На python можно сравнить длину строки и размер множества, полученного из этой строки. Поскольку в множестве элементы не повторяются - длины будут равны только в том случае, когда в строке нет повторяющихся симоволов.  (`if len(line) == len(set(line)) ... `)

Comment: Ваш текст - это сплошная строка без обрывов, или с `\n\r` ? Было бы хорошо дать пример "текста".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отфильтровать строки, в которых любые символы повторяются:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    if len(line) == len(set(line)): # all chars in the line are unique
        print(line, end='')
```

Используется условие для уникальности символов, предложенное [@Anton в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867163/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-cut-sed-awk#comment1403035_867163).

[Пример](https://ideone.com/9594LX):

```
$ echo $'abc\nded\nfghi' | lines-with-uniq-chars
abc
fghi
```

Это поддерживает и не ascii символы, которые могут более одного байта занимать в текущей кодировке (locale). Это не поддерживает символы состоящие из нескольких Unicode сode points (к примеру, `ё` -- `U+0435` `U+308`). Если хочется поддерживать такие буквы, то см. [Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/52873/23044)

Comment: Класс, ищет в разы быстрей чем баш-хак. Спасибо за ссылочки.

Answer (score 2):

Hackers delight!

Логически, задача разбивается на

- подсчитать длину строки
- подсчитать количество уникальных символов
- если оба значения равны, вывести строку

*./get_line_uniq_chars.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

make_strings()
{
    strings /dev/urandom \
        | head -c100k \
        | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\t//g' \
        | fold -s -w40
}

get_lines_uniq_chars()
{
    local line_ln
    local uniq_chars

    while read -r line; do
        line_ln="$(echo "$line" | wc -c)"
        uniq_chars="$(echo "$line" \
            | grep -o . \
            | sort -u \
            | paste -s -d '\0' - \
            | wc -c)"

        if [[ "$line_ln" == "$uniq_chars" ]]; then
           echo "$line"
        fi
    done
}

main()
{
    make_strings | get_lines_uniq_chars
}

main "$@"
# End of script
```

Что получаем, если нужно читать из файла замените функцию make_strings чтением из фала `cat "$1" | get_lines_uniq_chars`

```
~$ time  ./get_line_uniq_chars.sh
CBn{|F>1OSpR!j0lkeY%XT]UwPH"gW
,8KbSi6>Y\_7N';fvnXtj+1`@Fgy0)
v0o&}Fmjb7E89K>DHWY2dy_CJf[*Z4
Ly>G7&=(/Q-nOgf;^jKX.2zu`U$'!9
J}]^7nmt16iuWGF4~[Y/"*\yL>rM?A
^!iu1aT4GF_@klnA%$&?BeU";M=<+|
u1{+B8k2z,tVm5Lq6e'AyF~HOGo3<X
plP\mwK5MIVa"<!L7n^UyR3;eC,rqO
M%b'=#[]P`a{.7B!wFZe8QCmg~+I9T
|Hw/~(8!7IO'k`5)$:W-sPCG]r+#L_
[urVw7zJvg.]eO^cQ>~d)Eq<Ka?8%f
zY;}RAi{H~yfqld?Uv5"O\De[+Cg*|
G$I02y7e1KBgqZl:M\*bS~Xus+k}DW
NC1{Yq0ciBD2)\Q<7?]sUhRy!#I6A[
real    0m13.880s
user    0m9.366s
sys     0m17.788s
```

Comment: u cool ! thx )  работает . А если скажем нужно допустить однократное повторение символа (или максимально возможное N раз), есть мысли, как это можно сделать опционально?

Comment: @Bl0wfish имет значение каких символов? если нет то: `если ( длина_строки - количество_допустимых_повторов) == количество_уникальных`. Могу дописать как опцию к функции get_lines_uniq_char

Comment: Не имеет значения какого конкретно именно символа допускается повтор, правило должно относится ко всем символам строки. (Если играет какое-то значение - мои символы -буквы англ (и строчные и заглавные)+цифры.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_dup(strings):
    used = set()
    for letter in string:
        if letter in used:
            return True
        else:
            used.add(letter)
    return False


def only_without_dups(string):
    return [string for string in strings if not has_dup(string)]


# Тестировка

strings = ["Hello, world", "abcdABCD", "abcdAbCD", "xyzXYZ"]
result  = only_without_dups(strings)

print(result)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ['abcdABCD', 'xyzXYZ']
> ```

---

Объяснение:

Функция `has_dup()` собирает использованные символы строки в множестве `used` и сравнивает всякий последовательный символ со знаками в этом множестве - командой

```
     if letter in used:
```

Когда совпадает, значит, что символ в строке повторился, и функция немедленно завершается, возвращая значение `True`.