# Шаблон для поиска последовательности вида - Аа аА Бб бБ

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Какой шаблон в PCRE равносилен следующим примерам?

```
Аа
аА
Бб
бБ
```

Заглавная или строчка и строчка или Заглавная буквы одного типа.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение для PCRE**

Тут можно использовать

```
(\p{L})(?!\1)(?i:\1)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/5cKnpt/1).

**Подробности**

- `(\p{L})` - Группа №1: любая буква, и
- `(?!\1)` - сразу после этой буквы, не должно быть точно такой же буквы в том же самом регистре,
- `(?i:\1)` - но должна быть такая же буква в любом регистре (`(?i:...)` — группа, в которой осуществляется регистронезависимый поиск).

**Решение для Python**

Так как нет возможности использовать группы с модификаторами и `(?i)([^\W\d_])(\1)` работает также как `([^\W\d_])(\1)(?i)`, придётся воспользоваться тем, что предоставляет нам Python:

```
import re
s = "Аа аА  Бб  бБ АА ЬЬ"
print([x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(?i)([^\W\d_])(\1)', s) if x.group(1).lower() == x.group(2).lower() and x.group(1) != x.group(2)])
```

См. [онлайн демо](https://ideone.com/kUyc3z).

Тут `(?i)([^\W\d_])(\1)` находит букву, а затем - в регистронезависимом режиме - такую же букву, а потом `if x.group(1).lower() == x.group(2).lower() and x.group(1) != x.group(2)` помогает отфильтровать совпадения.

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить это нужно для Python скрипта.

Comment: @Hellseher Тогда о каком PCRE вы вообще говорите? В Python встроена библиотека `re`.